# Is this type of question too localized?

Tags: discussion, voting-to-close

I saw a question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/porting-openatiums-poor-mans-activity-to-drupal-7, and I wonder if such a question is too localized. It's about porting a specific function taken from Open Atrium to Drupal 7.

Where do we draw the line of questions being too specific to be something we should answer?

Answer (score 2):

One could also argue that it is not a question in the first place. There are no specific questions. It is more an implementation request.

You can't "answer" it with a few sentences, you can only write/port/implement it.

And this is IMHO not the platform for such requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question needs to be answered in several steps which is why I gave up on accomplishing the task of porting the module in the first place. It's a very useful Views field handler which is used throughout OpenAtrium.

The first question is how to convert these two lines of code from D6 api to D7 api since [db_rewrite_sql() now has become hook_query_alter()](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#db_rewrite_sql) and the $subquery and $main variables were constructed using some Views voodoo.

```
$subquery = db_rewrite_sql($subquery, $view->base_table, $view->base_field, array('view' => &$view));
$main     = db_rewrite_sql($main, $view->base_table, $view->base_field, array('view' => &$view));
```

Of course, there are several other instances of the DB api that have changed which is why this is a complicated problem. But, yes, it is a big problem with many complicated parts so I'll just delete the original post.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's quite broad but also can't be answer per se but I think a reasonable answer would be to point him to migration documentations like for [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7) and views 2 to 3 if it exists.